# I need to know the exact date with millisecond in C#

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I tried to use DateTime.Now but its present the date with hour, minutes and seconds but I need in addition of it the milliseconds too.
how can I get it? thanks.

Comment: DateTime has a Milisecond property.

Comment: `DateTime.Now.Millisecond`, or `Ticks` or use a Win32 call to a perf counter (like `Stopwatch` does) for very high resolution.

Comment: ....and, when you get it, it's quite possibly out-of-date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DateTime has milliseconds, the [MSDN for DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.millisecond.aspx) Even gives an example:

```
DateTime date1 = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine("Date with milliseconds: {0:MM/dd/yyy hh:mm:ss.fff}", date1);
```

The `fff` is milliseconds in the format string.

Comment: oh thanks didnt know it! btw how can I transfer all the date to milliseconds? is it possible?

Comment: milliseconds since what? You can have a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/system.timespan.aspx) in milliseconds... but a date to milliseconds doesn't make sense.

Comment: I actually dont need the date just the hh:mm:ss.fff

Comment: Create a timespan using the dates hh.mm.ss.fff and then call `TotalMilliseconds` on it, for total milliseconds elapsed in the day.

Comment: To get more decimals, you can use e.g. `Console.WriteLine("Date with seven decimals to the second: {0:o}", date1);` or just `string t = date1.ToString("o");`. But note that even if a `DateTime` has a resolution of a tenth of a microsecond, the clock inside your computer is not very precise, and the `.Now` property is only updated once in a while. So don't think that the digits give the "real" time in some way.

Answer (score 1):

DateTime.now or DateTime.UtcNow does have milliseconds included if you look for them.  However, on some older operating systems it's not possible to distinguish times down to the millisecond level.  I used to have a server running Windows Server 2003, and times there were only accurate to within 15.625 milliseconds.

Comment: Any instance of DateTime will have Milliseconds property, not just DateTime.Now or DateTime.UtcNow.